# Editing running journey email to reference the new Content Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, email-studio

My Journey email is currently referencing a content block and the HTML code has below ampScript

Example :

```
%%=ContentBlockbyKey(“Old_Content_Block”)=%%
```

Now I want to change the above code to reference new Content Block instead of the old block,
Example:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyKey(“New_Content_Block”)=%%
```

So if I make the changes like this in the existing code, will the journey send old or new content after making the changes. Does it not break the journey??

Comment: Why not set up a simple journey and email and test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Salesforce's documentation on this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5).

If you're updating AMPscript, the documentation states that you need to pause and republish its associated triggered send via Interactions > Triggered Sends > Journey Builder Sends. Once you've updated your email, do the following:

1. Navigate to Interactions > Triggered Emails > Journey Builder Sends, to locate your journey and email.
2. Click 'pause' on the email(s) you wish to update.
3. Re-check the box(es) for the emails you're updating and click on 'Publish Changes'
4. Re-check the box(es) again and click on 'Start/Restart'

Comment: Thanks for the info. Should I pause and edit the email OR if I edit the mail and follow the above steps is fine?

Comment: Either should work fine. One extra thing I tend to do is click on the email name once in the triggered send to refresh the reference to the email. This is needed when updating user-initiated sends, which carry some of the same features. SF knowledge here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317287&type=1&mode=1